# Node cron not executed on production

Tags: node.js, cron, production, cron-task

I use a web server ([o2Switch](https://www.o2switch.fr/)) who use a Cpanel interface, my nodejs app is running with the `setup node.js` module.

My rest api use Nodejs with express and a database mongoDb atlas, my front is a Vuejs app, everythings works fine in production, but i have one cron with [node-cron package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron):

```
// scripts/myscript.js
const cron = require('node-cron');

const script = cron.schedule('00 20 * * *', async () =>  {
    console.log('PASSED')
},
{
    scheduled: true,
    timezone: "Europe/Paris"
}
);

script.start()
```

The script is import inside app.js:

```
// Scripts
require('./scripts/myscript')
```

My nodecron works fine in local and i don't have any trouble, but on production is not executed.

I do a lot of test:

- It's `10:00(am)` and i setup my cron on `05 10 * * *`, this will work. But is never reexecuted the following day.
- It's `10:00(am)` and i setup `00 12 * * *` this will never works.
- I setup every minute `* * * * *` this works every minute.

What is seems, is my server is like standby after a couple of hours (i don't know if it's possible).

My vuejs app works fine at any time, the request works and do not have trouble.

Comment: What do you mean by "*my server is not running all time*"? If your service (ie probably `app.js`)  is not running at 20:00 o'clock (8 PM) then the task won't be executed. There is no logic of executing missed schedules ...

Comment: I'm not sur, is a developer who told me "Your server is on mutual server, nodejs need to be run in virtual machine manually".

But i do a lot of test and i fund this works if I put a few minutes of delay. I have update the end of my answer with details.

Comment: There is not enough information to help you. As long as `app.js` is running on your server (and your server is running), this schedule will execute. We don't know about your infrastructure, ie whether for instance your server is stopped/paused after some idle time. And if that happens, how your service reacts on being restarted/unpaused ...

Comment: Thanks for your response, i update all topic, i try to be more precise. I hope this help !